# How to pick randomly UIColor saved in NSArray?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsarray, uicolor

I saved colors in a NSArray like this:

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor blackColor], [UIColor darkGrayColor], nil];
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pick randomly the UIColor from this NSArray.

How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[arr objectAtIndex:arc4random() % arr.count];
```

Comment: Better yet, `[arr objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(arr.count)];`